# Why does my name reappear sometimes?

Tags: support, profile-page, real-name

I removed my real name on all StackExchange websites.

But sometimes I go in my profile and my real name is back.

It happened to me a dozen times.

Any idea of why?

Perhaps one of the following reasons (on StackOverflow):

- I replaced to other fields in my profile this afternoon.
- I had a big activity too.
- serveral people came to my profile today.

Comment: Could be a caching issue - I've changed my name very often on Meta, and have never encountered this

Comment: I had this problem again on StackOverflow there's 10 minutes. Perhaps one of the following reasons: I replaced to other fields in my profile this afternoon. I had a big activity too. And 3 or 4 people came to my profile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your real name field is empty, it is filled with the name that's given by your Open Id provider. If you don't want that, just type something in the box.

Note that only moderators and yourself can see it anyway, normal users can't.

Comment: Oh ok, I logged with Facebook on my iPhone there's ~15 minutes and I saw my real name was back there's 10 minutes on my PC. Thank you for the explanation. (I didn't know users couldn't see it)